# Filter Spark dataset using custom function in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am relatively new to Spark and I am trying to filter out invalid records from a Spark Dataset.
My dataset looks something like this:

```
| Id | Curr| Col3 |

| 1  | USD | 1111 |
| 2  | CNY | 2222 |
| 3  | USD | 3333 |
| 1  | CNY | 4444 |
```

In my logic, each Id has a vaild currency. So it will basically be a map of `id->currency`

`val map = Map(1 -> "USD", 2 -> "CNY")`

I want to filter out the rows from the dataset that have Id not corresponding to the valid currency code. So after my filter operation, the dataset should look something like this:

```
| Id | Curr| Col3 |

| 1  | USD | 1111 |
| 2  | CNY | 2222 |
```

The limitation I have here is that I cannot use a UDF.
Can somebody help me in coming up with a filter operation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a data frame out of the `map` and then do an inner join with the original data frame to filter it:

```
val map_df = map.toSeq.toDF("Id", "Curr")
// map_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Id: int, Curr: string]

df.join(map_df, Seq("Id", "Curr")).show
+---+----+----+
| Id|Curr|Col3|
+---+----+----+
|  1| USD|1111|
|  2| CNY|2222|
+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. The dataset might have a row with a valid Id but an invalid currency code. Like (1, CNY, 333). In this case I want to remove such entries as well. I will update my question to reflect this case.

Comment: Do you want `Id` and currency both match at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I basically want to keep only the rows that have valid `Id` and `Currency` information. Any row that has mismatching `Id` and `Currency` column should be removed.

Answer (score -2):

```
val a = List((1,"USD",1111),(2,"CAN",2222),(3,"USD",4444),(1,"CAN",5555))
val b = Map(1 -> "USD",2 -> "CAN")
a.filter(x => b.keys.exists(_ == x._1)).filter(y => y._2 == b(y._1))
```